# Template parse error when using ng2-boostrap datepicker with angular2-seed project

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng2-bootstrap

I am trying to use the datepicker from the ng2-bootstrap in the angular2-seed project and I get the following error. I am using the latest version of the angular2-seed project (angular 2.0.0-rc.3)
Thanks in advance for any suggestions on what I am doing wrong.

```
platform-browser.umd.js:2311 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:No provider for NgModel ("eight:290px;">
    <!--<datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" showWeeks="true"></datepicker>-->
    [ERROR ->]<datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" [showWeeks]="true"></datepicker>
</div>"): AboutComponent@20:8
```

My about.component.html

```
<wrapper>

<alert type="info">ng2-bootstrap hello world!</alert>

<div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" [showWeeks]="true"></datepicker>
</div>

<alert *ngFor="let alert of alerts;let i = index" [type]="alert.type" dismissible="true" (close)="closeAlert(i)">
{{ alert?.msg }}
</alert>

<alert dismissOnTimeout="5000">This alert will dismiss in 5s</alert>

<button type="button" class='btn btn-primary' (click)="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
```

My about.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AlertComponent, DatePickerComponent} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
 selector: 'wrapper',
 moduleId: module.id,
 templateUrl: './about.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./about.component.css'],
 directives: [
    AlertComponent,
    DatePickerComponent,
    CORE_DIRECTIVES
 ]
})
  export class AboutComponent {
    date:Date = new Date();
    alerts:Array<Object> = [
    {
      type: 'danger',
      msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.'
    },
    {
      type: 'success',
      msg: 'Well done! You successfully read this important alert message.',
      closable: true
    }
];

  closeAlert(i:number) {
    this.alerts.splice(i, 1);
  }

  addAlert() {
    this.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!', type: 'warning', closable: true});
  }
}
```

My Bootstrap code

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms } from '@angular/forms/index';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from './app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

if ('<%= ENV %>' === 'prod') { enableProdMode(); }

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
   disableDeprecatedForms(),
   provideForms(),
   APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
{
   provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
   useValue: '<%= APP_BASE %>'
 }
]);
```

Comment: You don't need to add `CORE_DIRECTIVES` to providers. They are provided globally since quite some time.

Comment: I think you are somehow mixing old and new forms. https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/638 Can you please post how your `bootstrap(...)` looks like?

Comment: Have updated the question with the bootstrap code

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am trying to upgrade my project from angular2 beta to rc3. That is why CORE_DIRECTIVES was there. I have removed it from the component.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. If you look at the issue @GünterZöchbauer mentioned you can see it has an attached [pull request](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/pull/631). When it will be merged it should fix this problem.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I have commented out the @angular/forms for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PR was merged so now you need to can use

1. NgModel or FORM_DIRECTIVES from @angular/forms
2. and bootstrap(...,[...disableDeprecatedForms(),provideForms(),...]